# Usar o Bundle e/ou só putExtra?

Tags: java, android

#### Para passar dados entre `activity`, tenho 2 formas:

**1. Usando `Bundle`:**

```
public void teste(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Teste.class);

    Bundle bd = new Bundle();
    bd.putString("site","google.com");

    i.putExtras(bd);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**2. Sem usar `Bundle`:**

```
public void teste2(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Teste.class);
    i.putExtra("site","site2.com");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

---

#### Dúvidas:

- Por que então deveria **usar o Bundle**?
- Teriam "**particularidades/motivos**" para o uso do `Bundle`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nos dois exemplos você está a usar um Bundle.

A diferença é que no primeiro exemplo é você que o cria, enquanto que no segundo ele é criado internamento pela classe Intent.

O método `putExtras()` recebe um Bundle criado externamente.
Ao ser utilizado, o Bundle interno é "mesclado" com o passado ao método.

O método `putExtra()` é usado para adicionar valores ao Bundle interno.

É possível usar o método `putExtras()` e depois o método `putExtra()`, ou vice-versa, para adicionar novos valores.

Uma possível razão para usar um Bundle criado por si é ter a necessidade dos valores serem adicionados a ele em diferentes fases da execução da aplicação.

Por exemplo. no caso de querer repassar os valores passados à Activity para outra Activity:

```
private Bundle extras;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        // Obter valores individualmente
    }else{
        extras = new Bundle();
    }
}
```

Mais tarde ao chamar a outra Activity

```
public void startActivityXXX(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,Teste.class);

    //Eventualmente adicionar mais valores
    extras.putString("site","google.com");

    i.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(i);
}
```